# aiogram, telegram bot, проблема с inline клавиатурами, не получается добавить многоуровневую клавиатуру

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

я хотел добавить второй уровень инлайн клавиатуры, чтобы при нажатии на первую инлайн клавиатуру пользователю приходила вторая клавиатура[image: на картинке это с 26 по 32 строку]

```
import aiogram
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from config import TOKEN
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.utils.markdown import text
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher

bot = aiogram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = aiogram.Dispatcher(bot)

genres_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
genres_keyboard.add(
    InlineKeyboardButton('Action', callback_data='action'),
    InlineKeyboardButton('MMO', callback_data='mmo'),
    InlineKeyboardButton('RPG', callback_data='rpg')
)

delivery_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
delivery_keyboard.add(
    InlineKeyboardButton('Доставка курьером', callback_data='courier'),
    InlineKeyboardButton('Самовывоз', callback_data='pickup')
)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in ['action'])
async def process_genre(callback_query: aiogram.types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.from_user.id,
        reply_markup=delivery_keyboard,
        text='Вы успешно выбрали жанр "MMO", теперь необходимо выбрать вариант доставки!')


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in [ 'mmo'])
async def process_genre(callback_query: aiogram.types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Вы успешно выбрали жанр "MMO", теперь необходимо выбрать вариант доставки!')
    genre = callback_query.data


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in ['rpg'])
async def process_genre(callback_query: aiogram.types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Вы успешно выбрали жанр "RPG", теперь необходимо выбрать вариант доставки!')

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in ['courier', 'pickup'])
async def process_delivery(callback_query: aiogram.types.CallbackQuery):
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
        delivery = callback_query.data


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: aiogram.types.Message):
    await message.reply('Здравствуйте!\nВы находитесь в магизине игр\nВыберите жанр игры :', reply_markup=genres_keyboard)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    aiogram.executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Зачем прикладывать один и тот же код сначала картинкой, а потом текстом? Оставьте только текст.

Comment: на картинке я хотел показать не код а то что на 27 строке не используется callback

Comment: ну так вы его и не используете, по этому он и затемнен

Comment: @ZxNuClear вот я и хотел узнать как это можно исправить, чтобы клавиатура работала

Comment: @ZxNuClear здравствуйте! у меня новый вопрос, он связан с вашим прошлым ответом, не могли бы вы его посмотреть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то мудрено вы хотели это реализовать. Все делается намного проще - когда вы планируете собирать и обрабатывать данные, которые вводит пользователь, то почти всегда можно использовать FSM, если вводимых данных больше единицы. Я бы сделал это вот так:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher, FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token='ТВОЙ ТОКЕН')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Games(StatesGroup):
    game = State()
    delivery = State()


genres_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
genres_keyboard.add(
    InlineKeyboardButton('Action', callback_data='Action'),
    InlineKeyboardButton('MMO', callback_data='MMO'),
    InlineKeyboardButton('RPG', callback_data='RPG')
)

delivery_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
delivery_keyboard.add(
    InlineKeyboardButton('Доставка курьером', callback_data='courier'),
    InlineKeyboardButton('Самовывоз', callback_data='pickup')
)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()
    await message.answer('Здравствуйте!\nВы находитесь в магазине игр\nВыберите жанр игры:', reply_markup=genres_keyboard)
    await Games.game.set()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Games.game)
async def get_games(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['game'] = call.data
    await call.message.edit_text(text=f'Вы успешно выбрали жанр "{call.data}", теперь необходимо выбрать вариант доставки!', reply_markup=delivery_keyboard)
    await Games.next()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Games.delivery)
async def process_delivery(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['delivery'] = 'Доставка курьером' if call.data == 'courier' else 'Самовывоз'
    await call.message.edit_text(text=f'Вы выбрали жанр "{data["game"]}" и вариант доставки "{data["delivery"]}"')
    await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

ну а дальше делайте с данными пользователя что хотите, они находятся в `data['game']` и `data['delivery']`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!!